# Taking the rest of the list into account in filter

Tags: haskell, filter

I need to display the number of elements whose successor is greater in a list. For example, in the list [3,7,2,1,9] my function should return 2 because 7 is greater than 3 and 9 is greater than 1.
In order to do that,I was thinking to use the filter function:

```
greaterElems :: Ord a => [a] -> Int
greaterElems [] = 0
greaterElems [x] = 0
greaterElems (x:xs) = length (filter (< head xs) (x:xs))
```

However, this does not work as expected: it seems that Haskell always considers the second element of the list, as if "head xs" is calculated only once, but this does not seem normal to me since Haskell is lazy.
What am I missing and how could I fix my code in order to achieve my goal?

Comment: Hint: use `zipWith`.

Comment: `However, this does not work as expected: it seems that Haskell always considers the second element of the list, as if "head xs" is calculated only once, but this does not seem normal to me since Haskell is lazy.` I am not sure why you expected `head xs` to be calculated more than once, or why it would ever refer to any element other than the second one of the list. And that has nothing to do with laziness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [**`zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith) where we pass the list, and its tail. Indeed:

```
sucGreater :: Ord a => [a] -> [Bool]
sucGreater x = zipWith (<) x (tail x)
```

or as @RobinZigmond says, we can omit tail, and use `drop`:

```
sucGreater :: Ord a => [a] -> [Bool]
sucGreater x = zipWith (<) x (drop 1 x)
```

For the given sample list, this gives us:

```
Prelude> sucGreater [3,7,2,1,9]
[True,False,False,True]
```

I leave it as an exercise to the count the number of `True`s in that list.

Comment: The usual caveat applied here about `tail`: better to use `drop 1` in case the function is ever passed an empty list.

Comment: @RobinZigmond: well here it will not matter, since `zipWith` will first evaluate the first parameter. Hence even if you pass an empty list, it will work, due to laziness.

Comment: But it's silly -- there is a subtle error which is however cancelled out by a subtle conditional strictness.  Or you have the option to make it all total with 0 instead of 2 dependencies on subtle things...